# how can i include only one folder in Fortify SCA scanning using SCA mvn plugin on my project?

Tags: java, maven, fortify

I only want to perform the scanning on `./src` folder because `SCA` mvn plugin takes the root of my project by default and it throws undesirable results. How can I do that? by using tags in the pom.xml file?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Indicate in your pom.xml a profile

```
    <profile>
          <id>fortify</id>
          <modules>
            <module>modulea</module>
            <module>moduleb</module>
            <module>modulec</module>
          </modules>
     </profile>
```

Then run the SCA plugin targeting this profile